# Reducing the size of a ImageView programatically (with java code)

Tags: android, imageview

How to reduce the size of the imageview to 200x200 ?

This is my actual code:

```
 private ImageView splash;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
        splash = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        splash.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
        fl.addView(splash);
        fl.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setContentView(fl);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just Try This:

```
  ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image1);
  Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sc01);
  int width=200;
  int height=200;
  Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);

  image.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code before you add view to framelayout

```
splash.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,200));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 200 dip, the following should work.

```
int dips = TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
    200 , 
    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

splash.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(dips,dips));
```

if you want to get sp ( scaled pixels ) instead use TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP instead of COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, and if you want just 200 plain pixels, use

```
splash.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can set imageview size like this

```
imageview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,200));
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
```